# How to display image in android

Tags: android, wcf

I want to show image in my android app.For that i am calling my service,in that the image is in this format:

```
 image:[255,216,255,224,0,16,74,70,73,70,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0......].
```

How to display this image in android.

Comment: Your question is not clear

Answer (score 0):

can you explain it more detailed. does your image is in  base 64 format.If so then you have to decode the image and display it in imageview.

```
 byte[] b = Base64.decode(previouslyEncodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
        img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Here bytearray is, what you are getting from server

Answer (score 0):

To inform you this is known as byte array of image, You have to decode that array into [`Bitmap`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) using the [`decodeByteArray`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray(byte[],%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options)) method of [`BitmapFactory`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html) class like,

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this working for me

```
String myString = "[255,216,255....]";
try {
    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(myString);
    byte[] myArray = new byte[myString.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
        myArray[i] = (byte) arr.getInt(i);
    }
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(myArray, 0, myArray.length);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
    image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Explaining the steps:

```
Start by converting that string to a JsonArray
Convert all items in it to bytes and add them to an byte[]
Convert the byte array to a bitmap
Set that bitmap on your image
```

Comment: how to display it using json..like Name,Last Name i can display by using this: String Name = json.getString("Stu_FName"); and for displaying  myAwesomeTextview.setText("First Name: " + Name ), for image i am not getting how to do that.

Comment: here myString contains data which you get from json and above code will converts this format to image,and  image.setImageBitmap(bmp); will set image in to your imageview